# How to develop an Android Service/Application that can be used across android applications?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to develop an App/Service which can be used across any android applications.

For ex: I am reading SMS on Messaging App or Watsapp and i want to get meaning of any word/line.So i should be able to select the text and search about that word or a sentence. And this same type of searching could be done across applications wherever any TextView is present. Search result to be displayed on the current application page in a small dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get any value from any `TextView`. It is agains privacy and it is impossible to do.

You can use some public `ContentProvider` s to read SMS messages or some different texts from different apps.

Comment: @tasomanic: Here i am not taking about getting any value from text view. 
Ex: On web browser i select any text and do a right click i get option as Search on Google for "Behemoth". So i am talking about a kinda service or a plug-in type of thing. 
So is there any room for such implementation ?

Comment: That selection implementation is very custom and it is different in stock Browser, Chrome, Samsung and HTC browsers. In Chrome, it does Google search with the selected text. You cannot interfere this. But there is also a Share menu in Chrome for the selected text. If you register your Activity as a IntentFilter for android:mimeType="text/*" you can get that selected texts.

Comment: Ohh Is it ? Well it seems to be complex now but surely i will consider your input and try to implement the same.